# Вывод из models.py

Tags: python, django

Не получается вывести данные из БД в темплейт.

models.py. в таблицу table_a поле field_id является FK для table_b.

```
class table_a(models.Model):
    field_name = models.TextField(blank = False, null = False, default = 'Null')
    field_id = models.IntegerField(blank = False, null = False, default = 0)

class table_b(models.Model):
    field_2_name = models.TextField(blank = False, null = False, default = 'Null')
```

я вывожу данные таблицы table_a следующим образом файл Views.py

```
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    abs = table_a.objects.all()

    print(abs)
    context = {
        'abs':abs,
        }
    return render (request, "template.html", context)
```

при выводе я хочу заменить поле field_id из таблицы table_a на значение field_2_name таблицы table_b

в темплейте я вывожу следующее.

```
{% for abs in abs %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ abs.field_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ abs.field_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ abs.field_2_name }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

проблема в том, что если я вывожу по 1 значению из таблицы table_a то всё окей. но я хочу выводить больше 1 строки в темплейт и вместо field_id вставлять значение из второй таблицы table_b.field_2_name.

как я виже себе этот запрос , если его писать в бд.

```
select
    table_a.field_name
    table_b.field_2_name
from table_a
join table_b on table_a.field_id = table_b.id
```

Comment: Зачем {% for abs in abs %}  ? Чего мешает использовать разные объекты?{% for  cel in abs  %}

Answer (score 2):

1. Вам не надо явно задавать `blank` и `null` в `False`, они по умолчанию такие.
2. В `table_a` вы создали не внешний ключ, а просто целочисленное поле. Внешний ключ создается так:

```
table_b = models.ForeignKey(TableA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

3. В шаблоне у вас `{% for abs in abs %}`, так делать не стоит, поскольку получается, что вы на каждой итерации перезаписываете `abs`, который у вас является списком, по которому вы проходитесь в цикле. Правильнее будет так:

```
{% for row in abs %}
```

4. И наконец, чтобы получить связанные записи по внешнему ключу, вам нужен ещё один цикл:

```
{% for row in abs %}
  ...
  {% for rec in row.table_b.all %}
    ...
  {% endfor %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: а как в теплейте вывести только значение table_b.field_2_name  а не  ( я так понимаю это выводит все столбцы таблицы table_b)  ?

а как во вью опеределять модель ? подойдёт такой вариант который я писал выше ?

Comment: @Jazzis Вы наслаиваете своё решение независимо от поставленной задачи. Проблема лишь в переопределении объекта в цикле шаблона, и всего то. Остальное написанное Вами - частности и стиль.